# Returning "NOT FOUND" string instead of empty set from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table called tbl_pet_types:

```
+----------+-------------+
| pet      | type        |
+----------+-------------+
| cat      | mammal      |
| dog      | mammal      |
| goldfish | fish        |
| goldfish | seacreature |
| snake    | reptile     |
+----------+-------------+
```

I want to build a query that looks for type='amphibian' in the table, and returns

```
type       pet
amphibian  NOT FOUND
```

since amphibian is not found in tbl_pet_types

I'm trying to use IF() to do this:

```
SELECT IF(type=NULL, type, type), IF(pet=NULL, 'NOT FOUND', pet)
FROM tbl_pet_types
WHERE type='amphibian';
```

But the query still returns an empty set. How can i change my query to get the results I want?

Comment: Uh... You are asking it to return `'NOT FOUND'`. `:/`

Answer (score 0):

You might give this a try, but if you need to search for multiple types, it could get cumbersome:

```
SELECT 
    a.`type`,
    IF(b.`type` IS NULL, 'NOT FOUND', b.pet) as `pet`
FROM (SELECT 'amphibian' as `type`) a 
LEFT JOIN tbl_pet_types b
    ON a.`type` = b.`type`
WHERE type='amphibian';
```